# What does << mean in C?

Tags: c, operators, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Im having trouble understanding what << means in C. Im supposed to explain some code as a homework assignment, but it's kinda difficult to find an answer by googling.

It's related to programming a multi function shield connected to arduino (atmega328p chip)

Here's the line:

PORTB = ~(money << 2);

Comment: my teacher is such a good teacher, that he has not given us any books but presents hour long PP presentations expecting us to know everything

Comment: Oh dear. Good luck.

Comment: "Kind of difficult to find an answer by googling."  Some things are like that; some bodies of knowledge defy the instant-gratification answer.  Sometimes you have to read the whole book (at the risk, it's true, of learning more than just the one answer you're looking for today).

Comment: Most languages have lots of operators, some more obscure than others.  Most C references have a section devoted to all of them, though probably not in the introductory chapter 1.  In [these online course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html), `<<` and `>>` don't show up until [section 18.2.1](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4b.html).

Comment: `<<` means left-shift in C. Google "bitwise-operators" to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

From the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
>   the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
>   representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and
>   nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type,
>   then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> 5 The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1
>   has an unsigned type  or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative
>   value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
>   E1 / 2E2. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting
>   value is implementation-defined.

In fact this operation

```
money << 2
```

is equivalent to

```
4 * money
```